# cakephp3 bake console don't bake

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

I installed xampp7 and composer3 and I got cakephp3.1 with composer. Everything was ok and I saw cakephp homepage. Then I tried to start baking with this codes.

```
composer require --dev cakephp/bake:~1.0
```

and then

```
cake bake
```

But it gives me an error.

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Cake\Shell\Task\SimpleBakeTask' not found in 'src\Shell\Task\ShellTask.php' on line 6
```

I also tried the following codes and they were properly executed.

```
cake
cake migrations
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Bake is a plugin. So, just installing with composer is not going to cut it. You need to load it `Plugin::load('Bake');` in your `config/bootstrap.php` as you load any other plugins. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html

Comment: Thank you @AndreS. I did it. But it seems it's not enough because the error still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download cakephp-3.2-RC1 from github. It's bake console work properly and has no problem. I don't know what does cause the problem. But this is a simple solution that works for me :)
When I replaced the src/Shell folder of this version(cakephp-3.2-RC1) with that version, it's problem solved.